# playing video with MediaElement change colour of video

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, video

I am trying to play a video as part of the background of a grid.

I have this code in xaml:

```
 <Grid Width="1024" Height="650" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
        <Grid.Background>
            <VisualBrush>
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <StackPanel >
                        <MediaElement Name="myMediaElement"  >
                            <MediaElement.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
                                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>

                                                <MediaTimeline  Source="Videos/globe5.mp4" Storyboard.TargetName="myMediaElement"  
                 RepeatBehavior="Forever" />

                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </MediaElement.Triggers>
                        </MediaElement>

                    </StackPanel>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="12"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


       ....



    </Grid>
```

the video plays but its colour is changed.

How did I understand that the colour changed?

I used a colour picker and used it to pick colours of the boundary of the video when it is played as part of the application and when it played by a video player.
The colour picker detects different colours.

when I played with video player, all corners of the video had the same colour, but when I played it as part of the application, the four corners have different colours.

I think there is some kind of gradient applied to the grid, but I am not sure how I can remove it. I add `OverridesDefaultStyle="True"` to remove any styling that it may get from somewhere else, without any success.

How can I find why it changes the video colour and how I can remove it from this grid styles?

Comment: My guess is that the player is ignoring the color space (ie playing rec709 as 601)

Comment: @szatmary Is there any way that I can change it?

Comment: Check the player documentation. This is a common problem in chrome, and it can’t be changed there.